# How do I extract Year from the date column of a dataframe using pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I recently started working with pyspark and I am trying to get different ways in extracting the year from add_date column of a dataframe and create a new column named year to the same dataframe.

```
+-------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------+
|show_id|   type|title|  country|       date_added|
+-------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------+
|     s1|TV Show|   3%|   Brazil|  August 14, 2020|
|     s2|  Movie| 7:19|   Mexico|December 23, 2016|
|     s3|  Movie|23:59|Singapore|December 20, 2018|
+-------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use substring:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df2 = df.withColumn('year', F.expr('substring(date_added, -4)'))
df2.show()
+-------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------+----+
|show_id|   type|title|  country|       date_added|year|
+-------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------+----+
|     s1|TV Show|   3%|   Brazil|  August 14, 2020|2020|
|     s2|  Movie| 7:19|   Mexico|December 23, 2016|2016|
|     s3|  Movie|23:59|Singapore|December 20, 2018|2018|
+-------+-------+-----+---------+-----------------+----+
```

Comment: Thanks alot @mck. please can you refer me to materials where I can learn how to clean/manipulate/replace etc data. Thanks

Comment: you can read the docs https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/